# Whatsapp Chat Bot workflows available

Tags: node.js, twilio, botframework, chatbot, whatsapp

my team is developing a chatbot using nodejs botbuilder, LUIS, QnAMaker & Twilio  we've managed to build a chatbot

the problem is the Performance of the chatbot is a little less compared to other chatbots i've seen, i feel the callback from twilio is causing some delay cause when running in local bot emulator the performance is good.

so my question is that, is there any other way to create a chatbot for whatsapp other than twilio which would give me a better performance?

or any tips to improve performance?

Comment: Have you seen other WhatsApp bots perform better?

Comment: yes for example i used a bajaj finance bot to compare and the bajaj bot responds a lot faster

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, you can see a list of Twilio alternatives here: https://bstrategyhub.com/twilio-competitors-alternatives/

If you build a bot with C#, there are some adapters you can use for Infobip, MessageBird, and RingCentral: https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/master/libraries

If you want to stick with Node, you may need to make your own adapter.

Regarding performance, you'll need to gather telemetry to see where the messages are getting delayed and address the problem there. If the problem is on the WhatsApp side for example, you could try contacting WhatsApp support and ask them to look into it.